# How to add more input text box in dynamicreferenceparameter in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

```java
properties([parameters([
    [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
        choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML',
        omitValueField: true,
        description: 'Editable field when PARENT_PARAM is Others',
        name: 'ACTIVE_PARAM',
        randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178624',
        referencedParameters: 'PARENT_PARAM',
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript',
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [],
                sandbox: true,
                script: "return['undefined']"
            ],
            script: [
                classpath: [],
                sandbox: true,
                script:
                    """
                    inputBox="<input class='setting-input' name='value' type='text' value=''>"
                    inputBox="<input class='setting-input' name='value' type='text' value=''>"
                    inputBox="<input class='setting-input' name='value' type='text' value=''>"
                    inputBox="<input class='setting-input' name='value' type='text' value=''>" >>>>Here
                    """
            ]
        ]
    ]
])])
```

I was expecting more text boxes but it's not coming.